# How to give different caption to 4 subfigures in Figure environment?

Tags: floats, subfloats

I want to use two column environment to place 4 subfigures. But I am using Figure environment. What is the purpose of * in the following code and how can I mention different captions to four subfigures in the figure environment.

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Fig1.PNG}
\hspace{0.05\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Fig2.PNG}
\\[.5\baselineskip]
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Fig3.PNG}
\hspace{0.05\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Fig4.PNG}
\caption{Figures}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Sorry I Have modified code for figure environment

Comment: While you don't actually NEED the subfig or subcaption packages, they are much easier than doing everything yourself.  OTOH, you can even use a tabular to add text between images.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331118/how-do-i-align-both-baseline-and-caption-in-a-horizontal-tikzpicture-subcaption

Comment: Actually in subfigure environmnet spacing b/w subfigures is too broad. That is why I want to use Figure enviromnet. Is there any way to reduce spacing b/w subfigures in two column and subfigure environment

Comment: Subfigures are just minipages with captions.  \caption adds spacing (\abovecaptionskip and \belowcaptionskip), but you can pack 0.5\textwidth subfigures cheek to cheek.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what do you want. Something like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\subfloat[Caption of a]{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\qquad
\subfloat[Caption of b]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\\
\subfloat[Caption of c]{\label{fig:c}\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-c}}\qquad%
\subfloat[Caption of a]{\label{fig:d}\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\caption{Caption of figure}
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I use figure environment rather than {figure*} can I exactly fix the location of the figure at the top or bottom of the page. Yes I want this. But what is the advantage of using figure environment?

Comment: @jerry, in a 2 columns latex document (either `\twocolumn` or the `multicols` environment) use `\begin{figure*}` to create figures that span the entire width of the page. `\begin{figure}` span only one column. Is this the answer to your comment question? I thought you were using a one column document. Please give us a compilable MWE

Comment: No I am using 2 column environment. But the broblem with {figure*} is that it shifts figures to the next page even after using dblfloatfix package

Comment: Is there any environment or any package that fix this problem in two column environment?

Comment: @jerry, what about using the `multicols` package, see [How to place figure at the top or bottom of a page in twocolumn environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495421/89320)