# How to place figure at the top or bottom of a page in twocolumn environment?

Tags: floats

I'm using two column environment with dblfloatfix package. But my figures are  moving to the next page. How to exactly fix it at the top or bottom of the page. Beside I'm using {figure*} environment. I have read that twocolumn environment can not fix this problem. Is it so?What should I do. I need to wrire down paper in two column environment.

```
`\documentclass[twocolumn, 11pt]{article}`
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\thepage}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{figure*}[!tbp]
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{1000.PNG}
%\hspace{0.0005\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{10.PNG}
%\\[.5\baselineskip]
\smallskip
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{500.PNG}
%\hspace{0.0005\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{0.PNG}
\caption{Figures}
\end{figure*}`
```

Comment: That is the normal behaviour if you insert the `figure*` environment at a position in the code where the page has already started: by default it goes to the top of the following page. You may try loading the `stfloats` package: it allows for the optional `[t]` or `[b]`  ìn two column mode. Or you insert your environment previously in the code.

Comment: I'm getting this warning.Package dblfloatfix Error: Don't use the stfloats package!You're in big trouble now... \begin{document}.

Comment: I have already inseted dblfloatfix, float and stfloat package

Comment: And adding the optional argument does nothing?

Comment: I have modified my code included packages

Comment: You can't include both `dblfloatfix` and `stfloat`. With the latter, it works fine.

Comment: The suggestions in this answer are probably overkill, but some exceptions are explained: [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430)

Answer (score 1):

What about using  the `multicols` package instead of the `twocolumn` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{multicols}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Caption of a]{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\qquad
    \subfloat[Caption of b]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\\
    \subfloat[Caption of c]{\label{fig:c}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-c}}\qquad%
    \subfloat[Caption of a]{\label{fig:d}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
    \caption{Caption of figure}
    \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or using the same example with the `ltxgrid` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ltxgrid}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\columnsep1.5em
\begin{document}
    \onecolumngrid
        \begin{figure*}[tb]
        \centering
        \subfloat[Caption of a]{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\qquad
        \subfloat[Caption of b]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\\
        \subfloat[Caption of c]{\label{fig:c}\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-c}}\qquad%
        \subfloat[Caption of a]{\label{fig:d}\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
        \caption[Caption]{Caption of figure}
        \label{fig:myfig}
    \end{figure*}
    \twocolumngrid
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \lipsum*[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But In muticolomns environment I have to specifically mention the beginning and end of multi column. I only want to specify whether figure should be at the top or the bottom of the page.