# Single caption, double figure, figure notes, and left caption alignment

Tags: minipage, subcaption

I am using [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-manufacturing-and-service-operations-management/nmthwmpdpryp) template to write an article. I have the following to produce a side-by-side figure.

```
\documentclass[mnsc,nonblindrev]{informs3}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
    \FIGURE
    {\includegraphics*[width=1.08\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{images/TCchangewithdifferentscenarios.png}}
    {Change in $\Bar{\sC}\left(k\right)$ given percentage improvement in $C^M_p$, $w_p$, $f$, and $\mu_p$ for $|\sP|=100$ and 100 replications.\label{fig:cost_change}}
    {}
\end{minipage}
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
  \FIGURE
    {\includegraphics*[width=1.08\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{images/kchangewithdifferentscenarios.png}}
    {Change in $\Bar{k}$ given percentage improvement in $C^M_p$, $w_p$, $f$, and $\mu_p$ for $|\sP|=100$ and 100 replications.\label{fig:k_change}}
    {}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This produces the below:[image]

I have two objectives. First, I want to have a single caption for both of these figures and explanations below each as `a)` and `b)`. Second, I want to left align all the Figure and Table captions in the manuscript.

I want to note that the template has its own rules for figure addition. Please refer to [here](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/tex/latex/macros/Management-Science-template/Style-Instructions.pdf) (pages 7-8) for figure addition instructions to be able to follow why I use such a weird-looking method.

I checked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/latex-figures-side-by-side) and some other posts and you may claim my post is duplicate. But, my question is indeed template specific. I want to achieve the desired results without causing any conflict (due to package additions) with the current template design. For example, when I use the example with `subcaption`, the template produces a warning which bothers me.

Comment: If you HAVE ti use \FIGURE, try a \FIGURE without an image outside the minipages and \FIGURE without a caption inside the minipages.

Comment: Actually, I also thought about this but found it a bit unprofessional. Maybe not a bad idea. How about the left alignment; do you have any suggestion on that?

Comment: When all else fails, read the manual.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I tried to use \FIGURE, but it only adds some blank space. No matter how I did it, I could not get rid of the Figure captions. For example, I copy/pasted the mintage part into a single \FIGURE. It produces 3 figure captions. Any other suggestion?

Comment: It occurred to me that you should be able to put both images into one \FIGURE (possibly using a tabular), ergo one caption.  OTOH, they obviously don't want you to use left justified captions, or they would have made it an option.  If you do it anyway, all you are going to do is make them angry.

Comment: Can you add an answer with the code using tabular?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331118/how-do-i-align-both-baseline-and-caption-in-a-horizontal-tikzpicture-subcaption/331133?r=SearchResults&s=1|25.9106#331133  Note that you don't HAVE to use \subcaption.

Comment: They use `\subcaption` which I was trying to avoid because of this warning: Package caption Warning: `Unsupported document class (or package) detected, usage of the caption package is not recommended. See the caption package documentation for explanation.`

Comment: So don't use \subcaption.  Just put the text into the minipage.