# Can I put a figure and its caption inside a table cell?

Tags: tables, graphics

I am looking to achieve a grid layout of same-sized figures, each with its own caption underneath. My initial thought was to put a `\figure` environment inside a `\tabularx` like this

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llll}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{link.pdf}
  \end{figure}
  &
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{link.pdf}
  \end{figure}
  \\
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{link.pdf}
  \end{figure}
  &
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{link.pdf}
  \end{figure}
  \\
\end{tabularx}
```

but it fails with

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
```

What would the right way to do this? images will all have the same size, while I can't guarantee that for captions (which might *have* to be multi-line).

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64107299/how-to-arrange-images-into-grid-with-labels-on-the-side-in-latex) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62843801/caption-for-figure-into-a-table) but they seem overly complex, and they kind of separate logical structure from document structure (i.e.: captions separate from image).

Comment: the onlly reason to use `figure` is to allow the content to be floated to another position to help with page breaking, so just use `\includegraphics` without `figure` and if you need captions put the table inside a figure so it all floats together

Comment: `tabularx` is wrong here (if used it must always have `X` columns),  just use`tabular`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle will it work if the table stretches over multiple pages?

Comment: @cabohah no, but neither would your tabularx you could use longtable but you don't really need a table at all. It's not clear how many images per row you want, seems to be 2 but you show a table with 4 columns. I'd just use pairs of minipages no need for a tabular.

Comment: You need at least one X column for tabularx to work (see also tabular*).  You could put the entire tabular inside a figure, but \caption starts and ends with a \par, so you need to use p or X columns.

Comment: There are several examples on this site for putting "figures" into tabulars, although most are concerned with aligning the images and captions independently.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331118/how-do-i-align-both-baseline-and-caption-in-a-horizontal-tikzpicture-subcaption for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting images with the same size but different lengths of caption text side by side is problematic with caption above the image. Because of this, I would recommend to use caption below the image. With this, I would put each row into one `figure`, so they still would be able to float row per row:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Example of a short caption}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Example of a longer caption needing more than one line and
      therefore having linebreaks.}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Example of a short caption}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Example of a longer caption needing more than one line and
      therefore having linebreaks.}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Example of a short caption}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Example of a longer caption needing more than one line and
      therefore having linebreaks.}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Example of a short caption}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Example of a longer caption needing more than one line and
      therefore having linebreaks.}
  \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Example of a short caption}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Example of a longer caption needing more than one line and
      therefore having linebreaks.}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Example of a short caption}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Example of a longer caption needing more than one line and
      therefore having linebreaks.}
  \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

With caption above the image, it is difficult to decide, how the vertical position should be, maybe:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[position=top]{caption}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \caption{Example of a short caption}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \caption{Example of a longer caption needing more than one line and
      therefore having linebreaks.}
  \end{minipage}
  
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \caption{Example of a short caption}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \caption{Example of a longer caption needing more than one line and
      therefore having linebreaks.}
  \end{minipage}
  
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you don't want the figures to float, you could either use package `float` and add option `[H]` to all the `figure` environments in my examples, or just don't use any `figure` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]

\begin{flushleft}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{Example of a short caption}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \captionof{figure}{Example of a longer caption needing more than one line and
      therefore having linebreaks.}
  \end{minipage}
  \bigskip
  
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \captionof{figure}{Example of a short caption}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{Example of a longer caption needing more than one line and
      therefore having linebreaks.}
  \end{minipage}
\end{flushleft}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, thorough and clear! However I am sorry it doesn't work as the number of images is too large - Too many unprocessed floats: the number of images is in the thousands, and I need to fit about 16 per page

Comment: @simone if you have that many images you certainly don't want a float, you could use `[H]` then it won't use up the float stack at all. (or don't use `figure` and use `\captionof` for captions.

Comment: @simone It seems, you've not seen my last example, that does not use floats and is mentioned exactly for such situations.

Answer (score 2):

From comments you do not want to float the images, so `figure` is the wrong construct (although you could use `[H]` to make `figure` a non-float) here I just use parboxes, 3 per row but you could use more or less if you adjustthe width suitably.:

[image]

```
\parbox[b]{.3\textwidth}{\captionof{figure}{\raggedright#5}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#6}}\par
\medskip
}

\begin{document}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\imgrow
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-a}
{Another example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}{example-image-b}
{Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (x), \cos(x), x$) with a much longer caption}{example-image-c}

\end{document}
```